# Lighttpd with Kerberos

Tags: php, lighttpd, kerberos

I currently have Kerberos and the key distribution center set up on my Linux web server. Assigning tickets from the terminal works.

However, I have no idea how to setup Kerberos with Lighttpd/PHP to make it supply tickets for the client web browsers accessing the website or detect these tickets from the browser in the first place.

Comment: And read this: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1899

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.42 (released back in 2016) added support for Kerberos with lighttpd mod_authn_gssapi.  See [lighttpd mod_auth](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModAuth)